# remmina server & remmina client

Tags: 12.04, networking, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am a total beginner. I am totally frustrated in partial answers and I am unable to understand and the alphabet soup. The answers just confuse me. The instructions say to do this, but I have no idea how to do this. What fits in each of the required setup fields? How do I find out the correct format and data that each field requires? There is nothing I have been able to find that explains the basics of setting up remmina between two computers over the internet where the IPv4 addresses are known. Is the connection secure (encrypted en-route)? Where is the server to be located or is the client also the server? Any assistance would be helpful.

The two computers are Ubuntu 12.04 32 located in Argentina and Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 located in the States (both are in America).

My first problem starts under 'Profile':
'Name' May anything may go here?
'Group' Since there will be only the two ends, does Group require an entry?
'Protocol' Which would be best and which would be default supported by both ends?
'Basic' That should be the computer in the States, but what name should apply and in what format? Does it require a domain name or will an IP address suffice?
'Advanced' Seems the server must initiate the contact as 'Client name' 'Startup program' 'Startup path' fields are requested. What goes in each field and in what format?
'SSH' tunnel? Does that require a separate setup or is that built into either or both the server and client? Where is the server? and How do I get it? or Is it built into the client? What is the server-client relationship? or Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Good answers to your questions fill whole bookshelves.

It is quite easy to set up an rdp connection, if you are willing to just try before you go nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good answers to your questions fill whole bookshelves.

But, it is quite easy to set up an rdp connection...

I try to answer some of those questions and leading you in the right direction:

- You need to know formats for things, like you know formats for Date, currency and temperature in your Country. At least I hope you do or know how to ask Wikipedia for the correct format.
- You should use an RDP or VNC Connection. RDP should work out of the box, while VNC needs an extra VNC-Server Software on the machine you want to connect to.
- Relation: You have an RDP Client which loggs into another machine over network and sends back the Desktop, giving you the ability to interact with it from a distance.
- Profile Name ist the name of your connection Profil. Just choose a remarkable Name for your connection (I always use the name of the machine I connect to in the profile, but that is for you to choose.).
- Server Name: IP or Hostname of the Machine you want to connect to. ipv4 Ips have the format 000.000.000.000, where minimum is 0.0.0.0 and max is 255.255.255.255, Read an Article about TCP/IP if you are interestes in how this IP thingy works.
- User Name: Set the Username from an active user on the machine you want to connect to. Remeber the relation. All you do is connectiong to another machine with user Credentials.
- Passwort: read the last paragraph and guess for urself.
- Advanced: is for advanced users, if you are not an advanced user (if you do not know, you are not!) just do not touch the settings. Maybe you want to adjust the Quality of tansmitted Desktop pictures to higher Quality, if you have a fast Internet connection.
- In the end: you need to reach the machine you want to connect to. Since I cannot know how your networks are build, I cannot help you with that. I just want to point out that you might need some port forwarding at your remote machines network router (remote machine is the machine you want to connect to), so the connecting client can reach the remote Desktop.

Comment: Ponderous tome comes to mind. The documentation is sketchy and requires more than a basic understanding. What you provided did move me in a different direction which was an improvement over floundering. While not a solution, you did provide me with some clues as to what was needed and I am now exploring options I never before considered pertinent. I initially considered implementation to be modular, but I am finding documentation that suggests the requirement to integrate different applications. I am also seeing that remmina may not be the application for what I need. Thank you for your help.